# Factory and Resource Makes Angular UI Router not Work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I've been following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X_NZr_-RaLw and in my clientapp.js, when I insert

```
.factory('UserService', function($resource) {

    return $resource('https://troop.tech/api/users/:user', {user: '@user'});

});
```

Into my code, all the angular UI routing just stops working.

Context:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router','ngRouter'])


myApp.factory('UserService', function($resource) {

    return $resource('https://troop.tech/api/users/:user', {user: '@user'});

});


myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/dashboard');

    $stateProvider

        // HOME STATES AND NESTED VIEWS ========================================
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'partial-home.html'
        })

        .state('dashboard', {
            url: '/dashboard',
            templateUrl: 'partial-dashboard.html'
        })

        .state('about', {
            url: '/about',
            templateUrl: 'partial-about.html'
        })

        .state('register', {
            url: '/register',
            templateUrl: 'partial-register.html'
        });


    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');

});


myApp.controller('userController', function ($scope, $http, $window, UserService) {

  $scope.users = UserService.query();
      $scope.setDataForUser = function(userID) {
  };
      $scope.addUser = function(){
  };

    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In your factroy you use $resource as a parameter so you need inject angular built in resource liberary.

In index.html:

```
<script src="yourComponentFolder/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
```

And add a module `ngResource`...

```
   var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router','ngRouter','ngResource']);
```

[Reference in your Application that yoy follow](https://devdactic.com/improving-rest-with-ngresource/)

And one thing if you use `ui-router` not necessary to inject `ngRouter` so if you can discard `ngRouter` from module.